# Export Delimited Text File from SQL with a second delimiter for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There are many tutorials online that show how to export a SQL table to a delimited text file.

Unfortunately, the data I need to export contains carriage returns within a field.  This messes up the 'one line per record' export.

Is there a way to designate a second delimiter for each record?  That way I could export the table, do a search/replace on the carriage returns within the field, then do another search and replace to change the second delimiter back to a carriage return?

Comment: there's no csv standard. there's only csv-for-some-particular-app. multi-line csv is especially funky. there's no proper answer without knowing what app is going to be using this csv data. most likely you should use some other format, which doesn't care about things like line breaks, e.g. xml.

Comment: I'm using just a streamreader in c# to read line by line...I was going to do some crude notepad editing before that stage though.  XML seems like it could be a last resort.

Comment: well, if the csv is only going to be roundtripped through your external editing stage, then use whatever delimiter you want. even a simple `REPLACE(csvfield, "\n", "||\n")` or whatever could do the trick.

Comment: Just enclose the fields in quotes, and escape any quotes in the data. A number of existing csv parsers will still treat the \n as part of the same field, without starting a new record.

Comment: In SSIS you can define the Row Delimiter, why not define it as some character then export it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following, which assumes that the text is using `\r\n` for newlines instead of just `\n`:

```sql
REPLACE([StringField], CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), CHAR(31)) AS [StringField]
```